# Firefox will not display CSS

Tags: firefox, browser, html, css

I am creating a very basic website. Basically at the moment in is just a template. It has a simple navigation bars with no real link, and some text just to test the scroll and overflow. No Java or PHP or SQL yet, just plain HTML and CSS.

When I run the website in IE and Chrome it works beautifully, but when I use Firefox an error occurs. Firefox won't display any of my CSS, not a lick. Because it doesn't display the entire CSS I am thinking it is something with the the link to the CSS in my HTML page:

Other than that I can not think of why it is not displaying. I ask that you please don't tell me to clear my cache, or update Firefox, or that I am missing a bracket in my CSS. Not only have I tested these before but some wouldn't even fix the problem.

Thank you,
Sean

Comment: Do you have any errors on the console? Turn on the CSS log as well.

Comment: Perhaps consider adding a link to the site or at least accessible versions of the html and css involved. Debugging this without that information is likely next to impossible.

Comment: Well, the site at the moment is not up. Mainly because of this problem. I want the users to be able to use which ever browser they prefer.

Comment: With a little thought I was able to solve my error within my link:

<link href="homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" > 

I changed the href to go directly to the css not a specific path.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option: Firefox 22.0 (current version as of my posting this) has a menu option:

```
View -> Page Style -> No Style
```

Why don't you check to make sure the `Basic Page Style` is selected there. That's a Firefox-specific problem.